# OpenCL compiling with C++ bindings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, opencl

I'm trying to compile the [cl.hpp](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.hpp) from Khronos Groups with VS2010, and I have the following message:

```
1>c:\users\facundo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opencl\opencl\cl.hpp(4757): error C2039: 'resize' : it is not a member of 'cl::vector<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=cl_context_properties
1>          ]
```

How to compile C++/OpenCL projects on VS2010 correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cl::vector<>` has been deprecated.

By default cl.hpp should pick `std::vector<>` as the default vector class.

Maybe you defined `__NO_STD_VECTOR` or you are using `cl::vector<>` yourself?